# How to collect specific data?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a text file like this

```
abcdxxxxx
abcdxxxxx
1234567
-
abcxxxx
```

from that file I want to separate only the strings with `abcd` as header part.

Help me please.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you want something that outputs only the lines that begin with `abcd`? Does it absolutely have to be bash, or is a solution that uses, say, `grep` acceptable? What OS does this need to run on? What have you tried so far and what were the results?

Comment: grep acceptable bro @MichaelKjörling

Comment: never mind , I fount it. Thank you . grep abcd filename.txt >> result.txt

Comment: Write a C program that implements a regular experession

Answer (score 1):

Since each record (we can call it that) is on a single line, and you want only those that begin with a specific sequence of characters (`abcd` in the case of your example), we just need to find the lines that start with that string.

That is trivial to do with regular expressions, which GNU `grep` readily supports.

```
$ cat <<EOF > x
abcdxxxxx
abcdxxxxx
1234567
-
abcxxxx
EOF
$ grep '^abcd' x
abcdxxxxx
abcdxxxxx
$
```

The `^` at the beginning means "at the beginning of the line".